# Querying database for records that don't have a 2nd record canceling it out

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I'm trying to find a set of particular records. Here's what my table looks like...

```
tblA

ID             VouchID           Action       Amount         
1              177-17            Add          700
2              177-17            Update       1
3              198-01            Add          600
4              198-01            Update       620
```

So what happens here, is if a record was canceled/deleted, the action would be 'Update' and Amount would be updated to 1. In other words, the VouchID = 177-17, would not be counted/be selected in this query...

What I'm hoping to do here is only select records, that don't have a corresponding Update record with Amount = 1

```
Select distinct vouchID where Action='add'
```

However, this query does not take under consideration VoucherID's that have an 'update' action. Update action can be applied in two instances, in VouchID 177-17 the amount = 1 on action='update' that means, that the ADD action does not count, it's almost as if we removed the record all together (it's just there for record keeping). Another Update in case of VoucherID = 198-01, the update line and amount = 620, means that the Amount was updated by 20 to 620, that record i hope to be able to see in my end reuslt

Desired end result from above table:

```
ID             VouchID           Action       Amount   
3              198-01            Add          600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LEAD` (SQL Server 2012 and above):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, LEAD(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY VouchID ORDER BY ID) AS next_amount
  FROM table
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE (next_amount <> 1 OR next_amount IS NULL) AND Action='add';
```

**EDIT**

non-recursive CTE can be always replaced with simple subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
       LEAD(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY VouchID ORDER BY ID) AS next_amount
      FROM table) sub
WHERE (next_amount <> 1 OR next_amount IS NULL) AND Action='add';
```

**EDIT:**

Using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t1
WHERE Action='add'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1
                  FROM table t2
                  WHERE t1.VouchId = t2.VouchId
                    AND Action='Update'
                    AND Amount = 1
                  ORDER BY ID ASC);
```

Comment: Is there any way i can do this without CTE since I have to do a join with another table

Comment: @BobSki Sure you don't need CTE at all

Comment: thank you when i use LEAD SQL server tells me LEAD is not a recognized built-in function name :(

Comment: I will provide answer without LEAD then

Comment: It doesn't have to @PeterB I only want to be able to see the 'ADD' records that don't have a corresponding 'Update' with Amount=1. I'm joining it with another table (tblB) using VouchID and getting the actual data from there.

Answer (score 2):

> What I'm hoping to do here is only select records, that don't have a
>   corresponding Update record with Amount = 1

Seems easy enough with NOT EXISTS():

```
Select distinct vouchID FROM MyTable t1 where Action='add' 
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable t2 
  WHERE Action='Update'
  AND Amount=1
  AND t2.VouchId=t1.VouchId
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SQL Server 2008 or better?  If you are, I would try something like :

```
SELECT
    ID, vouchID, Action, Amount     
FROM tblA s
WHERE 
    Action='add' 
    AND NOT EXISTS(Select 1 from tblA l where l.vouchID = s.vouchID and l.Action = 'Update' and l.Amount = 1);
```